# How to order by multiple meta keys with WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress, filtering, meta, meta-key

I'm stuck with this since this morning.
I’m trying to order with two custom key in a custom post type.

```
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'my_new_post_type',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        'firstArray_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'my_first_key',
                            'value' => 'My first value',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        ),
                        'secondArray_clause' => array(
                            'key' => 'my_second_key',
                            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
                        ), 
                    ),
                    'orderby' => array(
                        'firstArray_clause' => 'ASC',
                    ),
                );
                $MyQuery = new WP_Query( $args);
```

So for "my_first_key" I just want it to exist and I want to order by the value of "my_second_key".
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!
For those who will be interested :

```
$MyQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                    'post_type'     => 'my_new_post_type',
                    'meta_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => 'my_first_key',
                            'value'   =>  "My first value",
                            'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        ),
                    ),
                    'meta_key'       => 'my_second_key',
                    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
                    'order'          => 'ASC',
                ) );
```

I don't know if I'm understandable with the names of my values but you can change my_first_key to 'category' and my_second_key to 'order'.

Answer (score 0):

Tested and verified

```
$MyQuery = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'     => 'my_new_post_type',
                'meta_query' => array(
                    array(
                         'meta_key'       => 'my_second_key',
                         'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
                         'order'          => 'ASC',
                        'key'     => 'my_first_key',
                        'value'   =>  "My first value",
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    ),
                ),
               
            ) );
```